# Writing a Shell Script - which can print the error and could continue to keep the input you just run in command line

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

I am writing a shell script (named "test-script.sh"). One feature is as below:

When I typing the script name in CLI and click `<ENTER>`, The script name will be keeped in CLI following with the cursor when an error encountered.

Such as:

me@ubuntu: $ test-script.sh `<ENTER>`

me@ubuntu: $ Sorry, you must input at least one parameter.

me@ubuntu: $ test-script.sh`[cursor]`            **<<<< Here the script name auto printed and following with the cursor.**

Let's take `echo ${!!d}` as an example. When you run `echo ${!!d}` in CLI, an error will print but the cmd `echo ${!!d}` will hold in CLI.
Here `echo` is my test-script.sh.

How to achieve this feature in my script?
**Thank you~**

Answer (score 0):

`echo $0` will print the script name: `$0` - is script name, `$1` is 1st CL argument, `$2` is 2nd CL argument and so on..., `$#` is number of argument.

Example:

output:

```
$ ./test_script.sh
Sorry, you must input at least one parameter.
here are the options:
1. for option one
2. for option two
3. for option three
./test_script.sh 1
do you stuff for option 1 here
$
```

Script:

```
#!/bin/sh

menu(){
        echo "here are the options:"
        echo "1. for option one"
        echo "2. for option two"
        echo "3. for option three"
}

if [ $# -eq 0 ];
then
        echo "Sorry, you must input at least one parameter."

        menu
        read -p "$0 " option
else
option=$1
fi


case $option in

"1") echo "do you stuff for option 1 here" ;;
"2")  echo "do you stuff for option 2 here" ;;
"3")  echo "do you stuff for option 3 here" ;;
*)
   echo
   echo "Invalid option: ${option}"
   echo "...exiting...";sleep 1
exit
   ;;
esac
```

Comment: if this answers your question than - accept this as an answer. (make the correct sign green)

Comment: Thanks again for your help!
But this is not what I want. When we use `read -p`, we cannot edit the script name $0 by click backspace. 
What I want is the script have already EXIT, but the script name  was hold on the CLI and can continue to Edit.

Comment: Did you understand what I mean?
you could take `echo ${!!d}` as an example.
When you run `echo ${!!d}` in CLI, an error will print but the cmd `echo ${!!d}` will hold in CLI.